# Qt, qmake, Visual Studio 2008 and third party library

Tags: qt, include-path

it is my first question here; I think I did my homework pretty well, however I am still stuck with that problem:

I try to add in the include search path of my project property page in Visual Studio the include location I'd like to use. 
I already added OpenCV with NO PROBLEM at all, so I used the same syntax, but it is like VS2008 can't see the .h into the include folder: I get this at compilation:

Cannot open include file: 'FlyCapture.h': No such file or directory.

So, I tried to add the full path in my code, it then seems to find FlyCapture2.h, however, I get the error 'Image' unkown identifer at compilation...

Any help with this would be very, very appreciated!

Comment: So your question is mostly related to the Point Grey Flycapture SDK I assume and not su much Qt or Qmake? I imagine it's going to be quite difficult to answer this question. You could have a look at the command line your settings generate and see if there is any problem with the paths it includes.

Comment: Hi Bart, I'm not sure if it is really a Point Grey SDK related problem; my include search path is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Point Grey Research\FlyCapture2\include\FC1";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Point Grey Research\FlyCapture2\include\C";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Point Grey Research\FlyCapture2\include";C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv;C:\OpenCV2.1\include;$(NOINHERIT) The path are correct... The .h are there... :-/

Comment: Beside, I already tested those files with another project, where I tested the conversion between point grey images and OpenCV`s IplImage. Everything worked just fine... I guess this really is a make qmake nmake whatever-make problem :(

Comment: You know what's really funny: when I right click on #include "FlyCapture2.h" and choose open document, it actually opens the file!!! what is going on??

Comment: Are you by any chance using some custom build rules?

Comment: OK, sorry if my answer is irrelevant; by build rule, I guess you talk about my build command line? Here it is: qmake -project "LIBS+=c:/OpenCV2.1/lib/cv210.lib c:/OpenCV2.1/lib/highgui210.lib c:/OpenCV2.1/lib/cvaux210.lib c:/OpenCV2.1/lib/ml210.lib c:/OpenCV2.1/lib/cxcore210.lib c:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/FlyCapture2.lib c:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/FlyCapture2GUI.lib c:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/FlyCapture2GUId.lib" & qmake & nmake release

Comment: So what do you think? Can you help me?